# Android getWindow to set the background of my activity according to Listpreference

Tags: java, android

I've basically created a ListPreference where user would be able to choose from a list of options. After they have chosen one of the available option,the app will return to the main activity and the background image will change accordingly,however,it seems my app would't be able to detect the change in preference and change the background image.Can somebody please advice?Thanks!***Below snippet shows after my main activity resume,how it detects the change in preference and change the background image.

```
protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
          public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
              if(key.equals("listPrefwall")){
                tv.setText(prefs.getString("listPrefwall", "ondon"));   


                    if(prefs.getString("listPrefwall", "ondon")=="ondon")
                    {
                        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.ondon);
                        tv.setText("testing");
                    }
                     else if(prefs.getString("listPrefwall", "ondon")=="japan")
                     {
                         getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.japan);
                         tv.setText("pivot");
                      }
        }
          }
        };
    settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener((OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener) listener);

}
```

Comment: did you made sure you actually receive the listener event?

Comment: yeap i did, after  if(key.equals("listPrefwall")), i actually tried putting tv.setText(settings.getString("listPrefwall", "ondon")); and it works. Problem is that the if and if...else statement is not executed...i dunno why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your "settings" member retains a cached value? Try using the "prefs" object that gets passed to your listener.

Comment: I've edited the code using prefs as my object...however only the setText method of my TextView tv is executed....it seems my if...else statement is skipped....I still cant figure out why...any idea?

Comment: You probably want to use .equals() instead of ==

Comment: It seems there is a need to use .equal method to compare between two different String objects, thats why my if...else statement was not executed. Thanks for everything guys!